# Nesting NgIf and (click) in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have got a button which when clicked produces a number of child elements, I want to create a "collapse if the user clicks anywhere other than one of the child buttons" effect. To do this, I want to attach a `(click) = xyz()` to the whole page, but only have that active if the button has been expanded. Then I would position the child elements infront of the page wide selector (with css z-index). Is it possible to achieve that, or is there a better way of doing that?

Here is what I have so far (only toggles from the button click).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the declarative approach and just ignore events while collapsed

```
@HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
windowClickHandler(event) {
  if(!this.expanded) return;
  collapse();
}
```

another way could be a directive that is only enabled when expanded

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'globalClick'
  host: {
      '[style.display]':'"none"',
  }
}
class GlobalClick {
  @Output() globalClick:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
  windowClickHandler(event) {
    this.globalClick.emit(event);
  }
}
```

and then use it like

```
<span *ngIf="expanded" (globalClick)="collapse($event)">
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using window object directly,but is not recommended:

```
//save reference
this.listener = (event)=>{...};

window.addEventListener('click', this.listener);
window.removeEventListener('click', this.listener);
```